# Duvida com o hangfire.io, (PROCESSAMENTO BACKGROUND)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hangfire

Prezados estou utilizando o www.hangfire.io para processamento em background no meu sistema, até agora sem problemas, mas pesou uma duvida.

Se os Jobs estiverem sendo executados, e eu publicar uma nova versão do site, o que irá acontecer?  O Jobs continuam em execução ou são abortados?